# How to activate animation when mouse left the div/space?

Tags: html, css, menu, css-animations

So I was making the site that has menu that "slides" down from the top.
This is css code for aniamtion;

```
@keyframes slide-vertical-44-px-down {
    0%{height: 0px;}
    100%{height: 44px;}
}
```

I got it to work but i don't know how to make it come back to its original height when mouse leaves menu bar.

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: ground;
  src: url(Blackground-z88Bl.otf);
}

.top {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  height: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

.top:hover {
  height: 100px
}

#cool-lookin-box {
  /*aniamcja*/
  animation-name: slide-vertical-50-px;
  animation-duration: 400ms;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  /**/
  background-color: rgb(68, 68, 68);
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: ground;
  color: white;
  display: block;
  padding: 5px;
}

@keyframes slide-vertical-50-px {
  0% {
    height: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    height: 50px;
  }
}

@keyframes slide-vertical-44-px-down {
  0% {
    height: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    height: 44px;
  }
}

@keyframes slide-vertical-44-px-up {
  100% {
    height: 44px;
  }
  0% {
    height: 0px;
  }
}

.top:hover .menu {
  display: flex;
  animation: slide-vertical-44-px-up 200ms forwards;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 20px rgb(83, 83, 83);
}

.menu {
  display: none;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: rgb(128, 128, 128);
  cursor: pointer;
  animation: slide-vertical-44-px-up 200ms forwards;
}

.menu #menu-bar li {
  color: whitesmoke;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  transition: 400ms;
}

.menu #menu-bar li:hover {
  background-color: rgb(175, 175, 175);
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: rgb(65, 65, 65);
}

#test {
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="code.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="top">
    <div id="cool-lookin-box">
      <p>TESTOWY TEXT</p>
    </div>
    <div class="menu">
      <ul id="menu-bar">
        <li>First</li>
        <li>Second</li>
        <li>Third</li>
        <li>Fourth</li>
        <a href="https://google.com">
          <li>Fifth</li>
        </a>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="test"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

I've tried doing it with transitions but it doesn't work. I also tried doing it with another animation but it doesn't work either. I would be really thankful if somebody would help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Explanation

Animating height with CSS is a nightmare, if you have to use the "magic number" method. This also seems to be something you could accomplish more easily with transitions rather than animations.

The main reason I recommend transitions for this case, is because a hover will run a transition and the un-hovering will just run the transition in reverse, without the need for specifying a separate animation.

In the case you want to do something more than reversing a transition, then you should use an animation.

So now to tackle the height issue… Instead of using height, I'd recommend using either a transform with `translateY` and/or `scaleY`, or—my personal favorite option—`grid-template-rows`.

### Examples

#### Using Transition

##### With Transform

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  /* Helps with stacking context, but could be applied to essential elements only */
  position: relative;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: ground;
  src: url(Blackground-z88Bl.otf);
}

.top {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  height: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  /* Keeps it on top of everything */
  z-index: 20;
}

#cool-lookin-box {
  /*aniamcja*/
  animation-name: slide-vertical-50-px;
  animation-duration: 400ms;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  /**/
  background-color: rgb(68, 68, 68);
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: ground;
  color: white;
  display: block;
  padding: 5px;
  /* Make sure menu is hidden when collapsed */
  z-index: 10;
}

.top:hover .menu,
.menu:hover {
  /* display: flex; (not necessary) */
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 20px rgb(83, 83, 83);
  /* Transform End */
  transform: translateY(0);
}

.menu {
  display: flex; /* Changed to flex, as "none" cannot be eased yet */
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: rgb(128, 128, 128);
  cursor: pointer;
  /* Transition */
  transition: transform 200ms ease;
  /* Transform Start */
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}

.menu #menu-bar li {
  color: whitesmoke;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  transition: background-color 400ms ease;
}

.menu #menu-bar li:hover {
  background-color: rgb(175, 175, 175);
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: rgb(65, 65, 65);
}

#test {
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="code.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="top">
    <div id="cool-lookin-box">
      <p>TESTOWY TEXT</p>
    </div>
    <div class="menu">
      <ul id="menu-bar">
        <li>First</li>
        <li>Second</li>
        <li>Third</li>
        <li>Fourth</li>
        <a href="https://google.com">
          <li>Fifth</li>
        </a>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="test"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

##### With Grid Template Rows

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  /* Helps with stacking context, but could be applied to essential elements only */
  position: relative;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: ground;
  src: url(Blackground-z88Bl.otf);
}

.top {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  height: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  /* Keeps it on top of everything */
  z-index: 20;
}

#cool-lookin-box {
  /*aniamcja*/
  animation-name: slide-vertical-50-px;
  animation-duration: 400ms;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  /**/
  background-color: rgb(68, 68, 68);
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: ground;
  color: white;
  display: block;
  padding: 5px;
}

.top:hover .menu,
.menu:hover {
  /* display: flex; (not necessary) */
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 20px rgb(83, 83, 83);
  /* Grid Template Rows End */
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
}

.menu {
  display: grid; /* Changed to grid */
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: rgb(128, 128, 128);
  cursor: pointer;
  /* Transition */
  transition: grid-template-rows 200ms ease;
  /* Grid Template Rows Start */
  grid-template-rows: 0fr;
}

/* Necessary to collapse with grid-template-rows */
#menu-bar {
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.menu #menu-bar li {
  color: whitesmoke;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  transition: background-color 400ms ease;
}

.menu #menu-bar li:hover {
  background-color: rgb(175, 175, 175);
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: rgb(65, 65, 65);
}

#test {
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="code.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="top">
    <div id="cool-lookin-box">
      <p>TESTOWY TEXT</p>
    </div>
    <div class="menu">
      <ul id="menu-bar">
        <li>First</li>
        <li>Second</li>
        <li>Third</li>
        <li>Fourth</li>
        <a href="https://google.com">
          <li>Fifth</li>
        </a>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="test"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

#### Using Animation

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  /* Helps with stacking context, but could be applied to essential elements only */
  position: relative;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: ground;
  src: url(Blackground-z88Bl.otf);
}

.top {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  height: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  /* Keeps it on top of everything */
  z-index: 20;
}

#cool-lookin-box {
  /*aniamcja*/
  animation-name: slide-vertical-50-px;
  animation-duration: 400ms;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  /**/
  background-color: rgb(68, 68, 68);
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: ground;
  color: white;
  display: block;
  padding: 5px;
  /* Makes sure menu is hidden when collapsed */
  z-index: 10;
}

.top:hover .menu,
.menu:hover {
  /* display: flex; (not necessary) */
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 20px rgb(83, 83, 83);
  /* Open Animation */
  animation: open-menu 500ms ease;
  transform: translateX(0);
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
}

.menu {
  display: grid; /* Changed to grid */
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: rgb(128, 128, 128);
  cursor: pointer;
  /* Close Animation */
  animation: close-menu 200ms ease;
  transform: translateX(100%);
  grid-template-rows: 0fr;
}

@keyframes open-menu {
  from {
    transform: translateX(100%);
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(0);
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  }
}

@keyframes close-menu {
  from {
    transform: translateX(0);
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(0);
    grid-template-rows: 0fr;
  }
}

/* Necessary to collapse with grid-template-columns */
#menu-bar {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.menu #menu-bar li {
  color: whitesmoke;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  transition: background-color 400ms ease;
}

.menu #menu-bar li:hover {
  background-color: rgb(175, 175, 175);
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: rgb(65, 65, 65);
}

#test {
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="code.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="top">
    <div id="cool-lookin-box">
      <p>TESTOWY TEXT</p>
    </div>
    <div class="menu">
      <ul id="menu-bar">
        <li>First</li>
        <li>Second</li>
        <li>Third</li>
        <li>Fourth</li>
        <a href="https://google.com">
          <li>Fifth</li>
        </a>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="test"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

I hope that helps!